# Scale inheritance : what's the scale of the child object

Tags: bones, geometry, scale

Kind of a math question : If I have an object parenting another, the scale is inherrited. But if the parent has a scale of (1,2,1), what's the scale of the child?

If their axes are aligned, it will be (1,2,1). But if the child is rotated of 90° along the Z axis, it will be a scale of (2,1,1) wrt the child axes.

If the general case, what's the scale of a child, depending on the angle between the child and the parent?

Exemple :

[image: reference]

[image: x2 y scale]

[image: random rotation]

Comment: hello, please edit your question and show your images here

Comment: This is matrix multiplication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix .  The scale component of a 4x4 matrix is the diagonal (xyzw, where w is just always 1.0.)  The other variable we need here is the axis of rotation-- 3D angles can't be represented by single angles.  But a child with rotation and inherited non-uniform scale has *shear* and its transformation cannot be broken up into independent loc/rot/scale components-- if you unparent with keep transform, you will lose part of the transform.

Comment: @Nathan yes, I've seen that this deformation is not pure "scale". But if I set another bone, and have it copyScale this one (in world space), what will its scale be ?

Comment: @sayanel It is the diagonal of its transform matrix.  Its transform matrix is the multiplication of its inherited matrix (possibly the identity matrix, for a root object) with its inverse edit mode matrix with its transformation matrix with its edit mode matrix.  (If we place all bones at 0,0,0 in world space axes we can ignore inverse and edit mode matrices.)  Read up on matrix multiplication and on transformation matrices.